# Copy all documents from a specific folder, to a new folder as soon as it is created

Tags: designer-workflow, folder, copy

I want to copy all documents from a specific folder (Templates) resides under any library to library PROJECTS as soon as a new folder is created under inside this library.

Folders under PROJECTS with  is created automatically through Dynamics 365 integration whenever a Project is created in Dynamics 365.

I can place TEMPLATES folder under any library (May be under same Projects library)  which makes the workflow easy to implement.

Can I achieve it using SharePoint Designer workflow ?
Please advice.

Thanks,
Javed

Answer (score 0):

Hi just create workflow with trigger "Item is created". In SharePoint 2010/2013, there is no out-of-box workflow action to **move a file** from one library to another. Simple solution is copying the file and deleting it afterwards.

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: I want to copy files every-time  in new folder (created automatically) from Template folder (contain mutiple files) and dont want to move.